# Local storage item returns null value

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am storing token in local storage . The problem is I see its value in the browser through developer tools but when I do localStorage.getItem('authToken') its returning null

I tried even async way, but its not working

```
Code

    //local-storage.js
    export const loadAuthToken = () => {
        return localStorage.getItem('authToken');
    };

    //auth.js
    const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
```

I am supposed to get the correct value.But instead getting null value for authToken

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('token')` and `localStorage.getItem('authToken')` is a different thing. what you see in your developer tools?

Comment: Sorry that was typo.I meant localStorage.getItem('authToken')

Answer (score 1):

The `localStorage.setItem('authToken')` and `localStorage.getItem('authToken')` is a `asynchronous` task.
Sometimes you run `let token = localStorage.getItem('authToken')` just after the `setItem` will fail, so you get a null, so please put the  `getItem` operation after some delay.

You can use something like this :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    let token = localStorage.setItem('authToken');
}, 50);
```

Same for getting data from localstorage like

```
setTimeout(function() {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
    }, 50);
```

OR you can use `AsyncStorage` instead of `localstorage`. AsyncStorage is more promising than localstorage.

```
await AsyncStorage.getItem('loginStatus')
      .then(value => this.setState({ loginStatus: value }))
      .catch(e => console.log('err', e));
```

Comment: can u please share the code ? actually this is perfect I am even using this in my code and its working fine.

Comment: One doubt, should I add this in auth.js or local-storage.js